# Setting linux file permissions when running python on Windows not working using chmod()

Tags: python, linux

I am running a python script from Windows, it is writing to a linux file share mounted as a samba drive.

```
file_path_csv_ae = "//samba.scp.mycompany.net/other/pv_compliance/adverse_events.csv"
file_path_csv_ing = "//samba.scp.mycompany.net/other/pv_compliance/active_ingredients.csv"

   
try:
    df_adverse_events.to_csv(file_path_csv_ae)
    df_ingredients.to_csv(file_path_csv_ing)

    os.chmod(file_path_csv_ae,    stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR | stat.S_IROTH | stat.S_IWOTH | stat.S_IXOTH | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IXGRP)
     
    os.chmod(file_path_csv_ing,   stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR | stat.S_IROTH | stat.S_IWOTH | stat.S_IXOTH | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IXGRP)
except Exception as e:
    log_event(log_file, f"Error: {e}")
    sys.exit(0)
```

I am not seeing rwx rwx rwx on the file permissions being created. I am seeing rw- rw- ---

I suspect its because the os.chmod() module is running on Windows.

Is there a way to set user, group and world permissions on the file in linux, when running python from Windows, as these scripts are run from Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: There are some twirks around how Samba maps Windows file permissions to the underlying UNIX file system permissions. So your issue is generally related to Samba, not to python.

Comment: @treuss I suspected it was that the "os" library calls I am making, are being run from a windows "os"